# How to use images uploaded with custom implementation of thickbox like the_post_thumbnail() functionality

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails, thickbox

I have create a custom post type with meta boxes.

In metaboxes I have create some fealds that the use can use the WordPress ThickBox Media Dialog to upload his/her images for each post seperatly.

From the other side, the WordPress, when I upload an image as a Featured image, gives me some functions like the

```
the_post_thumbnail()
```

that allowing me to choose the image size that I need in my template.

So, the question is, can I use any function looks like the above one to print out the image sizes I like, that the end user has upload through the media box custom fields ?

Comment: If those attachments are easily identifiable in some way you could copy `the_post_thumbnail()` function and change its name and the image it gets.

Comment: What do you mean by "*custom implementation of thickbox*"? And to cut to the chase: are the images being uploaded as **`attachment`** post-types, or as custom post meta, or as something else?

Comment: The images are uploaded as custom post meta. More specific, the images are uploaded as URL in post meta table. Is there a way to upload the imasges as attachment through a meta box ? With custom imlementation I mean, that the end user can click on a button into my metabox and then the default WordPress Media Manager will appear into the Thickbox.

Comment: Is there any way to get the image ID ? In that case I will modify my script, in order to work with the default way that WordPress works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not opposed to using a plugin to achieve this, I would recommend the [Multiple Post Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/) plugin. It's very simple to use and provides the same functionality as "the_post_thumbnail()" function.