# Muliple featured images (or just images) per post

Tags: post-thumbnails

Is there a way to have multiple "featured" images (or just images) per post...I mean without putting it into the regular text editor.

I would like to have some control where the images go...hence make it work the way the featured image works (i.e. a separate meta box)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use images uploaded with custom implementation of thickbox like the_post_thumbnail() functionality](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44483/how-to-use-images-uploaded-with-custom-implementation-of-thickbox-like-the-post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [at this Q](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/44494/13677).

Comment: Absolutely! Glad it works for ya.